# Trying to create multimedia schema with core service : nullreference error

Tags: 2013-sp1, core-service

> Getting **null reference** error while trying to create the schema.
>   Using Tridion 2013 SP1 and code written in C#

**Code Snippet** :

```
SchemaData mmSchema = (SchemaData)client.GetDefaultData(ItemType.Schema, locationId, new ReadOptions());    
var list = client.GetSystemWideList(new MultimediaTypesFilterData());
var multimediaType = list.OfType<MultimediaTypeData>().Select(mt => mt.Id);

LinkToMultimediaTypeData[] arrayLinkToMultimediaTypeData = new LinkToMultimediaTypeData[multimediaType.Count()];
var i = 0;
foreach (var item in multimediaType)
{        
    var allowedMultimediaType = new LinkToMultimediaTypeData { IdRef = item };
    arrayLinkToMultimediaTypeData[i] = allowedMultimediaType;
    i += 1;
}
mmSchema.Title = title;
mmSchema.Description = title;
mmSchema.Purpose = SchemaPurpose.Multimedia;
mmSchema.AllowedMultimediaTypes = arrayLinkToMultimediaTypeData;
mmSchema = client.Create(mmSchema, new ReadOptions()) as SchemaData;
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you improve your question noting the environment, versions, etc.

Comment: Can you check the number of items in multimediaType?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `foreach` loop you are redefining `i` each time, so `i` will always be 0.  Consequently I suspect the remaining items in your array will by default be null.

Comment: But atleast one last data will be there, though the others are null.So what I undersstand in this case multimedia type can not be null.Thank you.